# Struts 2 using getText in action class or beans

Tags: java, validation, struts2, gettext, resourcebundle

Is there a way to use `getText()` in action class or beans? I cannot find example of java coding in google search but can find in JSP coding. My example is as below:

```
public class LoanForm extends ActionSupport {

    public void validate(){
        if(this.getNameOfApplicant().equals("")){
            addFieldError(getText("error.card"), getText("error.invalid.name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getText()` if your action bean implements [`TextProvider`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/TextProvider.html). If you extend `ActionSupport` it's already implemented by default.

> To use `getText()` the action should implement `TextProvider` that
> what `ActionSupport` is for. If your action class extends
> `ActionSupport` then you can use default implementation of
> `TextProvider` and can use the code above.

---

For other beans you can get the action instance which implements a `TextProvider`. For example

```
ActionSupport action = (ActionSupport)ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation().getAction();
String text = action.getText("error.card");
```

---

But the first parameter in [`addFieldError()`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ValidationAware.html#addFieldError-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), doesn't need `getText()`. It's used for the name of the field which would have an error.

Answer (score 0):

You only add `extends ActionSupport` to your action class or beans, or create an instance of `ActionSupport` and call `getText()`. `getText()` is a method of `ActionSupport`.

Comment: I have extends ActionSupport in action class. But in the view, it still shows "error.invalid.name".. Is there any missing I need to do? e.g. set some config??

Comment: Is your properties file under `WEB-INF/classes` directory or is the line starting with `error.invalid.name=` in the properties file?

Comment: Or did you add the line `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" ...` in `struts.xml`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked by adding the line <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" ... in struts.xml

Comment: I'm happy to help you.